# add finish() to ImageButton click in custom view

Tags: android, activity-finish

I used a custom view to insert a common layout in the bottom of every layout and added setonclicklistener programmatically. But I want to add finish() to intent so that on opening new page the previous page gets finish. How to do this?

```html
Custom View

public class MenuView extends RelativeLayout {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.homemenu, this, true);
        
        

        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.home)).setOnClickListener(home); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.search)).setOnClickListener(search); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.locate)).setOnClickListener(locate); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.log)).setOnClickListener(log); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.event)).setOnClickListener(event); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.activities)).setOnClickListener(activities); 
        ((ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.profile)).setOnClickListener(profile);  
    }
    
   

    private OnClickListener home = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
            
            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    }; 
    
    private OnClickListener search = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Search.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    
    private OnClickListener locate = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Locate.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    
    private OnClickListener log = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Log.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    
    private OnClickListener event = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), CreateEvent.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    
    private OnClickListener activities = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Activities.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener profile = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Profile.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the way you are doing

```
getContext().startActivity(i)
```

same way use but you need to convert `getContext()` to `Activity`

```
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
```

If anywhere you are using this from `Fragment` you need to check whether its `Activity` or not.

```
if( getContext() instanceof Activity )
    ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
```

Comment: @RRR : `finish()` method is not part of `Context ` class but `getContext ()` method return a Context class instance. and `finish()` method is from `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` so if we need to call it then need a valid instance of Activity.Thanks

Comment: Thanks `((Activity) getContext()).finish();` works. But I'm trying to create fragment-like "no new instance" and "backstack" in activity and when the activity finishes it does animation. Any way to remove animation?

Comment: there is one method `getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);` to disable animation, you can use it in activity `onCreate()`